# iOS. Can add RN .a libs instead of installing RN environment？

Tags: ios, react-native

1. I create AwesomeProject with RN command.
2. open it with xcode and build success by simulator.
3. I find RN .a libs under folder 'Debug-iphonesimulator'.
4. create a new xcode project and add step 3 .a libs.
5. build success.
6. after copy RCTRootView alloc initWithBundleURL codes in AppDelegate, xcode build failed (simulator selected)  with 154 common errors :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "std::__1::system_error::system_error(int, std::__1::error_category
>   const&, char const*)", referenced from:
>         folly::throwSystemErrorExplicit(int, char const*) in libReact.a(JSBigString.o)   "std::__1::basic_streambuf >::setbuf(char*, long)", referenced from:
>         vtable for google::base_logging::LogStreamBuf in libReact.a(logging.o)
>         vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf, std::__1::allocator > in
>   libReact.a(logging.o)
>         vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf, std::__1::allocator > in
>   libReact.a(JSCHelpers.o)

I wonder if this way works? 
Is it necessary to install RN environment?